# How would I make this yellow more golden without affecting the white background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion

I want the white to be pure, but I think I'm turning the gold foil too much into yellow in the process of changing the brightness / saturation.

Here's the original:

[image]

and what I have currently:

[image]

As you can see, a lot of the gold foil turns into a yellowish color. The white part looks a lot cleaner though so I am satisfied with that. How would I adjust just the gold / yellow?

An example of the tone that I want is this:

[image]

Comment: Your question title & body seem at odds - one is asking how to increase the gold, the other to whiten the background. I tried to cover both in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Magic Wand to select your background serviette/napkin [a bit of feathering may be required, I did this fast & rough].
Save your selection before proceding, then keeping that selection add an adjustment layer, Curves.
Photoshop will auto-mask if you have a selection.

That way you can tweak the background whilst leaving your gold text untouched.

You can push it anywhere, from this…

[image]

to this…

[image]

… without touching the gold at all.

Restore your earlier selection inverted, & you can push the gold intensity separately.

You can use the same technique - Adjustments - with Vibrancy [or hue/sat] & push the yellow out of the ball-park.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make a Curve Adjustment Layer, click the White Point, click on your napkin. Then go into the Layer Style Blending Options on the adjustment layer. Yellow is essentially opposite Blue in RGB. Switch the Blend If drop-down to the Blue channel and bring the yellow side in.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Would you mind explaining this step by step? I am not familiar with PS so I'm not sure how to find the Layer Style Blending Options

Comment: @Edmund Quite confident you can search for "Layer Style Blending Options" or any other term you're unfamiliar with. If after you do research on your own you can't figure it out you can ask a new question explaining what you tried that didn't work and we can help you.